# Trying to get the mail of the user in the context and the logged in user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this mail model that represents mail sent between two users.

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="mail_sent")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="mail_received")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    trashed = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} sent {} a message".format(self.sender, self.receiver)
```

I have this user serializer to serialize the user data:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_connected = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    mail_sent = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    mail_received = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "id",
            "username",
            "role",
            "upgraded",
            "verified",
            "email",
            "settings",
            "is_connected",
            "mail_sent",
            "mail_received",
        ]
        depth = 1


    def get_is_connected(self, user):
        request = self.context.get("request")  
        if request and request.user.is_authenticated:
            logged_in_user = request.user
            is_connected = (
                Connection.objects.filter(
                    Q(userone=user, usertwo=logged_in_user) |
                    Q(userone=logged_in_user, usertwo=user)
                ).exists()
            )
            return is_connected
        return False
    
    def get_mail_sent(self, user):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and request.user.is_authenticated:
            logged_in_user = request.user
            mail_sent = user.mail_sent.filter(receiver=logged_in_user)
            serializer = MailSerializer(mail_sent, many=True)
            return serializer.data
        return []

    def get_mail_received(self, user):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and request.user.is_authenticated:
            logged_in_user = request.user
            mail_received = user.mail_received.filter(sender=logged_in_user)
            serializer = MailSerializer(mail_received, many=True)
            return serializer.data
        return []
```

How can I see only the mail sent between the user in the context and the logged in user, cause now I just get an empty array but if I only put the mail_sent as a field then I see the data

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the mail_sent and mail_received in the user model have related names , but they are not directly related to the logged in user insted of they are related to all user

```
def get_mail_sent(self, user):
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and request.user.is_authenticated:
        logged_in_user = request.user
        if user == logged_in_user:
            mail_sent = user.mail_sent.all()
        else:
            mail_sent = user.mail_sent.filter(receiver = logged_in_user)
        serializer = MailSerializer(mail_sent, many=True)
        return serializer.data
    return []
```

Do the same thing for get_mail_received

Comment: self.context is empty so it does not work